# could not find `__client_accounts_contributor` in the crate root

Tags: program, lifetimes, rustc

Attempting to 'anchor build' a project and running into errors with the #[program] macro. Unsure exactly what could be causing these. Tried reading the compiler error index but it didnt seem to help in this context.

Errors:

```
    error[E0432]: unresolved import `crate`
  --> programs/solfund/src/lib.rs:10:1
   |
10 | #[program]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^ could not find `__client_accounts_contributor` in the crate root
   |
   = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `program` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error: the `#[global_allocator]` in this crate conflicts with global allocator in: solend_program

error[E0637]: `&` without an explicit lifetime name cannot be used here
  --> programs/solfund/src/lib.rs:10:1
   |
10 | #[program]
   | ^ explicit lifetime name needed here
   |
   = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `program` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
  --> programs/solfund/src/lib.rs:10:1
   |
10 | #[program]
   | ^ expected named lifetime parameter
   |
   = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `program` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
help: consider introducing a named lifetime parameter
   |
10 ~ #<'a>[program]
11 | pub mod solfund {
12 |     use super::*;
13 | 
14 |     pub fn create_fundraiser(
15 |         ctx: Context<CreateFundraiser>,
 ...

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0106, E0432, E0637.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0106`.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `solend-program = { version = "the-version", features = ["no-entrypoint"] }` in your `Cargo.toml` file. Also, you might want to check any `&` you have around in your code especially if it's a string. You should use `String` rather than `&str`. I can't deduce much without looking at the code.